# Comcast's two step login

Tags: security

Comcast has changed their login process so it happens in two steps.  Instead of two input boxes for username and password, you submit your username first.  Then on a second page you enter your password.

https://www.comcast.com/Customers/CustomerCentral.cspx

> Due to some recent security
>   improvements, we now require you to
>   enter your user name and password in
>   two separate steps.

What could the security improvement possibly be in this system?  If anything it seems less secure since you can confirm the existence of a username independently from it's password.

Any ideas on what they're accomplishing here?

Comment: Not sure why they'd do this, but have you tested random usernames that are likely to not exist?  If they accept any username in the first step and only give an error after receiving both username and password, then they don't have to confirm that a username exists here.  (You can usually try to create a new account to check usernames anyway, so as long as that's possible it may not even be worth preventing that here.)

Comment: I tried with a non-existent username and they came back rightaway with "
Missing or Invalid Information"

Comment: I've noticed more and more websites doing this practice. I think it's more to foil browser-based password managers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that they are targetting specific phishing/keylogging software which is "used to" finding all the login information on the same page. It's making the job of some malicious software a little harder.

If you use the "automatically fill in my forms" feature of many browsers, this will also separate the login information into two separate entries in the browser's data store, again making things just a little harder for any software which might try to exploit this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Comcast is doing the same thing, but I know a lot of bank websites I use lately started doing the following:

- Prompt you for your username
- Look up an image and a string that you specified at your account creation.
- Display that image + string along with the password box.

The stated goal is so that, if you as a user notice that the image and string don't match what you picked when you created the account, you get suspicious and don't enter your password.

What is the benefit here?  I don't see any either, as an attacker's script can just look up the image and string from the real login page.  Maybe it makes dumb people feel more safe.

Comment: what is the banking or the said company going to get by making dumb people feel more safe? wouldn't that be cheating?

Comment: maybe they feel people will not use it if they aren't convinced it has security features.

Comment: It is probably the other way round, make smart people feel dumb making them wonder there is some hidden security feature that they are dumb to not understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange, on the password page they require your email and password, not the user name.

The user name is not a secret, as you use it in your mail address probably....

They still allow you to "stay signed in" ...

So Actually, I don't think there is a real security benefit

You can get directly to the 2nd login page if you bookmark it....

Answer (score -1):

Simply so when you login to more secure areas of my account, you need to reenter your password instead of use the remember-me function, so if someone gets on the computer, all they can do is access email from a normal session. Yahoo does this also.